Laravel Livewire form: no action on create button click
In Laravel Livewire, nothing happens when I click the "Create" button on the form.
namespace App\Livewire\Components;

use App\Models\ProjectLists;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class CreateListForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $name;
    public $note;
    public $image;
    public $planId;

    public $showForm = false;

    public function toggleForm()
    {
        $this->showForm = !$this->showForm;
    }

    private function resetFields()
    {
        // Alanları sıfırla
        $this->name = '';
        $this->note = '';
        $this->image = '';
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'note' => 'max:500',
            'image' => 'nullable|image',
            'planId' => 'required|exists:projects,id',
        ], [
            'name.required' => 'List name is required.'
        ]);

        if ($this->image) {
            $newPlan = ProjectLists::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'note' => $this->note,
                'image' => $this->image->store('images'),
                'project_id' => $this->planId,
            ]);
        } else {
            $newPlan = ProjectLists::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'note' => $this->note,
                'project_id' => $this->planId,
            ]);
        }

        if ($newPlan) {
            $this->resetFields();
            $this->toggleForm();
        }

        return Redirect::to('/plans');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.create-list-form');
    }
}

This is my Livewire class file:
<div>
    <button wire:click="toggleForm"
            class="shadow-xl text-xl bg-gray-200 h-14 w-30 pl-4 pr-4 rounded-md text-center font-medium align-middle hover:text-orange-500 hover:shadow-xl focus:text-orange-600 focus:bg-gray-100 transition-all"
            wire:loading.attr="disabled"
            wire:target="toggleForm">
        New List
    </button>

    @if($showForm)
        <form wire:submit.prevent="create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf

            <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ $planId }}">

            <div class="mt-6 p-8 border-2 border-s-2 rounded-md shadow-xl">
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <input type="text"
                           wire:model="name"
                           placeholder="Name"
                           name="name"
                           id="name"
                           class="p-3 placeholder:ml-3 block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:border-orange-500 focus:ring focus:ring-orange-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:shadow-sm">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <textarea wire:model="note"
                              placeholder="Note"
                              name="note"
                              id="note"
                              class="p-3 placeholder:ml-3 block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:border-orange-500 focus:ring focus:ring-orange-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:shadow-sm"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <input type="file"
                           wire:model="image"
                           name="image"
                           id="image"
                           class="p-3 placeholder:ml-3 block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:border-orange-500 focus:ring focus:ring-orange-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:shadow-sm">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <button type="submit"
                            wire:loading.attr="disabled"
                            class="px-4 py-2 bg-orange-500 text-white rounded-md shadow-sm hover:bg-orange-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 transition-all">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    @endif
</div>

This is yjr livewire.blade file.
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/plans', [ProjectsController::class, 'index'])->name('projects.index');
    Route::post('/plan/create', [ProjectsController::class, 'create'])->name('projects.create');
    Route::get('/plan/{plan}', [ProjectsController::class, 'show'])->name('projects.show');

    Route::post('plan/{plan}/lists', [CreateListForm::class, 'create'])->name('lists.create');
});

This is my route.
Everything seems okay, except for data creation. When I click the "New List" button, it opens a form. I fill it out and click the "Create" button, but nothing happens. There are no errors, no results, and no data is saved. I don't understand what is happening. I'm still a newbie. What could be the problem here?
U have a point about validate. I change my code:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Components;

use App\Models\ProjectLists;
use http\Env\Request;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


class CreateListForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $name;
    public $note;
    public $image;
    public $project_id;

    public $showForm = false;


    public function mount($plan)
    {
        $this->project_id = $plan;
    }
    public function toggleForm()
    {
        $this->showForm = !$this->showForm;
    }
    private function resetFields()
    {
        $this->name = '';
        $this->note = '';
        $this->image = '';
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'note' => 'max:500',
            'image' => 'image',
            'project_id' => 'exists:projects,id',
        ]);

        $newPlan = null;

        if (filled('image')) {
            $newPlan = ProjectLists::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'project_id' => $this->project_id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'note' => $this->note,
                'image' => $this->image->store('images'),
            ]);
        } else {
            $newPlan = ProjectLists::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'project_id' => $this->project_id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'note' => $this->note,
            ]);
        }

        if ($newPlan) {
            $this->resetFields();
            $this->toggleForm();
        }

        return redirect('/plans');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.create-list-form');
    }
}

When i try to save an image it's work but without image it's not working and nothing happens. No data is saved and no redirect.

Your Validation fails.
In Livewire when you validation fails, it doesn't run codes after validation, for example you can not use if (validation fails) statement so show error messages in your blade file and see validation fail messages.
